# FLOW that forces uppercase on creation and update

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I've been researching on a logic that enforce uppercase on a new record during its creation and update. I know how to do it through Apex, or workflow and even make a validation to require the user to use input the name in uppercase.

In this case it needs to be a flow, so far I've tried a record triggered flow but I cant seem to be able to pick up the names and update them as uppercase, specially when there are numbers or symbols.
[image]

Can somebody point me to documentation, video or tutorial on this? I know that there are other options but the requirement is that it is a flow.
PD: this is only for two particular records called "Stories" and "Locations"

Comment: Could you explain why this is needed via flows (when there are other options available)?

Comment: Using a formula as entry criteria should do the trick, then Update Record action. Tutorial: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/automate_business_processes More tutorials: https://unofficialsf.com/lightning-flow-tutorials/

Comment: @arut How would you do it then? My reason is that the client insisted that workflows are going to be outdated soon. But at this point any solution would do it.

Comment: I was wondering why not use validation rule instead (which you have mentioned yourself in the question). When I read this question, it almost sounded like you have this in apex ot validation rule, but trying to build this out specifically in flow. I can now see that its a migration of logic from workflow to flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mocked up a solution to this. It's just like @identigral said in their comment.

Create a record-triggered flow that updates the record name to uppercase (I used a Before Save Flow). Do this by setting the name to a 'formula' resource containing the formula `UPPER({!$Record.Name})`. I added a formula entry criteria of `{!$Record.Name} != UPPER({!$Record.Name})` also, so the flow doesn't update the name every single time.

I'm not sure what you mean about numbers and symbols. In my case I just left them alone. Are you wanting to not allow numbers or symbols, or to do something else with them? In that case I would edit your question to be more specific about what what you'd like to do with those characters, or ask a new question. At least forcing to uppercase is solved here!

Comment: Man, this was so simple and worked like a wonder. I did not know that you could use formulas like that in flows, I have learned something new today, thank you so much!